# Access denied When Calling http from https

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a https Web Page.
I call another http webpage by JavaScript inside.

The alert shows `Access Denied`.

Here is my code.

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:2737/video";
try {
    if (document.all) {
        var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
        xdr.open('GET', url)
        xdr.send();
    }
    else {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', url, true);
        req.send(null);
    }
}
catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supose you are trying to do this with IE8 or IE9. Is that right?
The problem of this is shown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx):

> **7. Requests must be targeted to the same scheme as the hosting page**
>
> This restriction means that if your AJAX page is at
>   http://example.com, then your target URL must also begin with HTTP.
>   Similarly, if your AJAX page is at https://example.com, then your
>   target URL must also begin with HTTPS.

Thus, if this is the case, I am afraid it is not possible to do that

Comment: So, I have changed the way to call http page inside by using window.open(url).
but I need closing that after It loads complete.
Can you show me how to detect loading status of new page?

Comment: If I got it correctly, the call is performed in the opened window?

If that is so, you just have to add:
req.onload = function(){
   window.close();
}